# How do I check my code using the Sphere Engine API?

Tags: api, rest

From http://sphere-engine.com/services/problems

Sending requests
Follow the example of sending request to the service:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST
-d '{
    "code":"EXDOC"
    "compilerId":"11",
    "source":"#include<stdio.h> int main(){ // empty solution }"
    }'
"https://problems.sphere-engine.com/api/v3/submissions?access_token=xxxxxx"
```

I created a problem called HELLO_WORLD but when I send a post request for the problem I get

```
{"message":"Forbidden","data":[]}
```

I have checked that my access token is correct as it works for other calls.

Comment: Sorry guys this is because I didn't have premium access to Sphere-Engine, They don't allow this call in the free version.

Answer (score 0):

```
$token = '***********';
$get_submission_id = curl_init();   

curl_setopt_array($get_submission_id, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.compilers.sphere-engine.com/api/v3/submissions?access_token=*******',
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    language => $lang,
    input => $input,
    sourceCode => $code
)
)); 

$get_ideone_results = curl_init();

$submissions_id =  $results->id;

$url = 'http://api.compilers.sphere-engine.com/api/v3/submissions/'.$submissions_id.'/?access_token=***********&withSource=1&withInput=1&withOutput=1&withStderr=1&withCmpinfo=1';

usleep(2000000);

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
```

kindly check the code and share your thoughts

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed.

Answer (score 0):

i think that's because the problem code (EXDOC) does not exist. try creating a new problem and use its problem code